# Install and remove a plugin in c# web application (asp.net mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, plugins

I'm looking for a solution that enables installing and removing plugins in an asp.net MVC application.

I know a little about Reflection,But I need to know a solution to make install and remove plugins in my application just like Wordpress.

Is that possible?
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/565934/ASP-NET-MVC-plugin-framework  i thing this is what your are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what I'm looking for.